# Pausing a new BackGroundWorker until previous completes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am struggling with threading.
The problem is when I am iterating trough foreach loop.

When setting `this.Document`, the application performs login, that is triggered with an event and takes few seconds to complete. In the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted` method I need to perform some actions that depend on current login information.

The problem is that before I can perform this action for the first file, the `this.Document` already changes making the application perform another login. This way I can never actually perform my actions.

My question is: How can I pause the next thread until previous thread has completed.
Is there any other solution to my problem?

I tried with `AutoResetEvent` but I got no luck. I set `waitOne()` just after the RunWorkerAsync call and `.Set()` in the RunWorkerCompleted. The code never gets to `RunWorkerCompleted`...

Here is the code:

```
    public void Start(object obj)
    {
       try
       {
          foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in this.CollectionOfFiles)
          {
              Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
              Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
              Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

          using (Stream stream = pair.Value)
              {
                primaryDocument = new Document(stream);

                DataHolderClass dataHolder = new DataHolderClass();
                dataHolder.FileName = pair.Key;
                dataHolder.Doc = secondaryDocument;

               //background thread call
                Worker.RunWorkerAsync(dataHolder);
              }
            }
          }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          // exception logic
}
       finally
       {
          // complete logic
       }
    }


    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       DataHolderClass dataHolder = ((DataHolderClass)e.Argument);
       // setting this attribute triggers execution of login event
       this.Document = dataHolder.Doc;
       e.Result = (dataHolder);
    }


    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // here I need to perform some actions that are depending on the current login
       DataHolderClass dataHolder = ((DataHolderClass)e.Result);
       this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ActionEvent>().Publish(new Message(EMessageType.Info) { Title = dataHolder.FileName });
    }
```

Comment: It was buisy when Worker.RunWorkerAsync(dataHolder); was hit again...

Comment: Do I get this right? Setting Document triggers Start somehow?

Comment: not... setting Document triggers login action (it is not shown here). And when I am in the worker_RunWorkerCompleted i need to do some action that check login. Login takes few seconds to complete and its an event based call. My situation is that when I get to worker_RunWorkerCompleted the login already changes since another item in collection sets this.Document...

Comment: Oh boy, you've got hell of a race condition there. If you are logging multiple times at once (intended?), why do you use single (this.Document) property? This desing seems odd.

Comment: its an unfortunate situation... but the design cannot be changed...

Comment: Only a comment but I would look at BlockingCollection with a size of 1.

Comment: If `RunWorkerCompleted` needs the current login, then do them in the same thread. If they are in different threads then of course one could be done before the other, that is what threads are designed to do...

Comment: Could you not just make a deep (static) copy of login information and pass it to the RunWorkerCompleted?

Answer (score 0):

no9,

Try the following:

```
System.Threading.ManualResetEvent _busy = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

void ResumeWorker() 
{
     // Start the worker if it isn't running
     if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(dataHolder);  
     // Unblock the worker 
     _busy.Set();
}

void PauseWorker() 
{
    // Block the worker
    _busy.Reset();
}

void CancelWorker() 
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
        // Set CancellationPending property to true
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        // Unblock worker so it can see that
        _busy.Set();
    }
}
```

then in your code run the method.

Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class SimpleWaitPulse
{
  static readonly object _locker = new object();
  static bool _go;

  static void Main()
  {                                // The new thread will block
    new Thread (Work).Start();     // because _go==false.

    Console.ReadLine();            // Wait for user to hit Enter

    lock (_locker)                 // Let's now wake up the thread by
    {                              // setting _go=true and pulsing.
      _go = true;
      Monitor.Pulse (_locker);
    }
  }

  static void Work()
  {
    lock (_locker)
      while (!_go)
        Monitor.Wait (_locker);    // Lock is released while we’re waiting

    Console.WriteLine ("Woken!!!");
  }
}
```

Can you use pulse ?
Taken from : [Threading in C# from albahari.com](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the design is terrible... but *if* you *need* to stick to it, you can set wait handles in a previous worker and wait for it in next. This is the minimal fix, still quite an abomination:

```
public void Start(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        BackgroundWorker previousWorker = null;
        DataHolderClass previousWorkerParams = null;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in this.CollectionOfFiles)
        {
            // signal event on previous worker RunWorkerCompleted event
            AutoResetEvent waitUntilCompleted = null;
            if (previousWorker != null)
            {
                waitUntilCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                previousWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => waitUntilCompleted.Set();

                // start the previous worker
                previousWorker.RunWorkerAsync(previousWorkerParams);
            }

            Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            Worker.DoWork += (o, e) =>
            {
                // wait for the handle, if there is anything to wait for
                if (waitUntilCompleted != null)
                {
                    waitUntilCompleted.WaitOne();
                    waitUntilCompleted.Dispose();
                }
                worker_DoWork(o, e);
            };

            using (Stream stream = pair.Value)
            {
                primaryDocument = new Document(stream);

                DataHolderClass dataHolder = new DataHolderClass();
                dataHolder.FileName = pair.Key;
                dataHolder.Doc = secondaryDocument;

                // defer running this worker; we don't want it to finish
                // before adding additional completed handler
                previousWorkerParams = dataHolder;
            }

            previousWorker = Worker;
        }

        if (previousWorker != null)
        {
            previousWorker.RunWorkerAsync(previousWorkerParams);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // exception logic
    }
    finally
    {
        // complete logic
    }
}
```