# Unable to manage threads in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, mvp

I have problems with treads in `BackGroundWorker` `doWork` method on my presenter class.

My first question is why doesnt `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()` work.
The code breaks after hitting the line first time. All i can do is set a timer...

My second question is why is `CheckDocumentError()` throwing "***The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it***" even if I am calling it with Dispatcher.

What am I missing here?
The relevant information is that setting the Document attribute and CheckDocumentError method both update UI.

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in (Dictionary<string, Stream>)e.Argument)
  {

      Document = new Document(pair.Value);

      Thread.CurrentThread.Join(5000);

      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
      {
        CheckDocumentError(Document);
      }));

  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect Thread.CurrentThread.Join to do? It makes no sense to join the *current* thread, this will just block the thread, as the current thread can't finish as it is waiting on itself. You join some *other* thread. As for your second question, it looks like you are accessing some object created on the main thread from inside your background thread. You are using CurrentDispatcher so whatever you're doing in CheckDocumentError, it is still running on the background thread.

Comment: You are right ... but I cant seem to find the solution for me... please check my reply that i gave to Sheridan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to figure out what exactly you're trying to do. Here is how you can initiate the updating of the UI from your worker thread in a way that actually updates it on the UI thread, avoiding the error:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker Worker;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        Worker.RunWorkerAsync("param");
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            tb.Text = "doing work: " + (e.Argument as string);
        }));

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            tb.Text = "finished work";
        }));
    }
}
```

Notice that since I am updating the UI from the background thread, I don't use CurrentDispatcher, I use the dispatcher in charge of the thread that owns the control I am updating (tb is a TextBox in the XAML file of the window).

I am not sure what to replace your CurrentThread.Join with as I don't understand the point of that part of the code. But CurrentThread.Join is definitely wrong, it's basically a self-inflicted deadlock on a thread.

Comment: Thanks svinja... could you help me out with joining threads... basicly when setting the Document attribute some events are fired and I need to wait for them. I think Thread.Join would work, but I am not aware what tread to join...

Answer (score 1):

The [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used when you want to perform some long running operation in a background thread so that the UI does not freeze. You are *not* supposed to interact with any `Thread` objects manually as this is all done 'behind the scenes' for you. Try this code instead:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{    
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in (Dictionary<string, Stream>)e.Argument)
    {    
        Document = new Document(pair.Value);
        CheckDocumentError(Document);
    }
}
```

For more help with using a `BackgroundWorker`, please refer to the linked page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so I just noticed a line in your question: *The relevant information is that setting the Document attribute and CheckDocumentError method both update UI.*

You *cannot* update the UI from the `DoWork` method because it is running on a background `Thread`. You'll need to use your `BackgroundWorker` *inside* that method on just the long running part in order to make this work.

Comment: the problem is that setting the Document property triggers an event. The CheckDocumentError method depends on the completion of that event... My original problem is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541607/pausing-a-new-backgroundworker-until-previous-completes/20544251?noredirect=1#20544251

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the instance of type `Document` in the background worker's thread. Then you try to access it from the Dispatcher's thread. That is causing the *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"* error, since the worker thread now owns the instance of type `Document`. Create the instance in the Dispatcher's thread.

Comment: Still the same exception. The exception happens when GUI is updated in CheckDocumentError method (a simple text field)

Comment: Use the dispatcher from the thread where you create the textbox instead of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`.

Comment: i cant find it ... thats the problem :/

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct. He is accessing the Document from the *background worker's thread*, the same thread where it was created, as he is using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, which will return the background thread's dispatcher. The problem is not the Document instance, it is something in the UI that he is accessing, and this triggers the error.

Comment: it is working if I use System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher. Its obvious to me now ... its a main dispatcher responsible for updating UI. I cannot access controls from this class so it is a acceptable solution. Cna you also help me Join threads?

Comment: Why can you not use `Sleep` instead of `Join`? If I understood you correctly, you wanted to wait for some stuff to happen in another thread, correct?

Comment: Because sleep is not safe. The login event that is invoked after setting the this.Document attribute depends on the connection ... it might take 1 second or 10.... the proper way would be to join threads, so the code continues after login is complete...

Comment: Then I probably don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the expected behavior you are after with the `Join` in the code above?

Comment: i figured after setting this.Document, that triggers login event in the background I should wait for it untill it is finished. Login takes various time to complete and sleeping the thread for 5 seconds before continuing does the job - but not always. I would like to wait for the login to complete and then continue...